# Override the wp_siteurl and wp_home not work

Tags: wp-config

I created a wordpress site and name hostname as x.co.uk, x.com, x.in...

In wp-option table the site and home url as x.co.uk. I want dynamically for loading other host name also.

So dynamically set WP_SITEURL, WP_HOME, i override the wp-config as

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
define('WP_HOME',    'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
```

but when i call home_url() it always return x.co.uk hostname

Thanks Advance

Comment: you can user   get_option('home')  or other    bloginfo('siteurl')   to get this site url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So dynamically set WP_SITEURL, WP_HOME, i override the wp-config as

```
    define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
    define('WP_HOME',    'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
```

> but when i call home_url() it always return x.co.uk hostname

`home_url()` does not make use of any WordPress constants. It uses a call to `get_option( 'home' )`. To use WP_HOME instead, short circuit `get_option()`:

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_home', 'wpse_114486_change_get_option_home' );
/**
 * Change get_option( 'home' ) and any functions that rely on it to use
 * the value of the WP_HOME constant.
 *
 * This is not fully tested. Many WordPress functions depend on the value of
 * get_option( 'home' ). The ramifications of this filter should be tested
 * thoroughly.
 */
function wpse_114486_change_get_option_home( $option ) {

    if ( defined ( 'WP_HOME' ) )
        return WP_HOME;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: WordPress does this already with the `_config_wp_home()` and `_config_wp_siteurl()` functions that are attached to their respective option filters (`wp-includes/default-filters.php:175`)