# Which built-in Wordpress files are safe to edit?

Tags: filters, wp-config, customization, settings-api

I begin to work with Wordpress, I'm developing a theme with many functionnalities into it, and I'm good with that.

My question does not have to do with theme development, but more with general knowledge about Wordpress. I would like to know which files are safe to edit in a standard Wordpress installation : files that will not be overwritten when we perform an update of Wordpress for instance.

I know of `wp-config.php`, but are all others at the root safe too ?

I ask this because I want to add filters in my Wordpress website and those filters will be independant of a plugin or a theme. Currently I added them in `wp-settings.php` but I found nowhere if this file is safe to edit.

Comment: *Core files will be overwritten on updates, so its not save to edit them.* 

Don't know what you are actually doing, but maybe you should ask another question, how to implement that without changing core files. Give some background information, so people really can help you. Besides that, personal statement, do not edit core files, in 99% there is another way anyway, because later on, when a update is needed, it is a real pain to resolve those core edits.

I know, because I regularly do that #$%7§! for clients..

Comment: If you're doing theme/plugin development the safest way to add functionality is to use the functions.php file or the plugin class. There are already a lot of filters to use to modify output and WP functionality. So my real question is why are you trying to modify the install instead of building on the platform.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but I found nowhere what are core files (which should not be edited). Are all files core files, except `wp-config.php`?

I understand I should not do what I did, and try to install my filters in the `functions.php` of my theme.

Comment: From your comment I tihnk that you know about the filters API and how to add custom filters to Wordpress but you want to add theme without being coded in a theme or in plugin. Have I understood correctly? Can you explain why? I can't imagine a situation where you may need that.

Comment: No I don't want to add theme, I want to add `pre_option_home` filter to be able to run Wordpress on multiple "domains" in development (dev1.myname.company.com, dev2.myname.company.com). If I add this filter in `functions.php` of my theme, it's too late. And this filter should apply for other themes anyways.

Comment: *Consider everything that comes with a vanilla WordPress installation a core file.* E.g. `wp-config.php` isn't a core file, because it comes only with the sample version of that file.

Comment: Then put that functionality in a (mu-)plugin.

Comment: Just found that I can do `update_option('siteurl', 'http://mywebsite.com')` in my theme to achieve the same result (but using a theme, and not built directly in my WP install). I'll look into mu-plugin. @ialocin, can you post your comment as an answer (consider everything that comes...), I will accept it, it best answers the original question. thank you.

Comment: Done and my pleasure. You might want to take a look at [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/114532/22534) regarding the `pre_option_home` filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Consider **everything** that comes with a vanilla WordPress installation a core file.* Core files will be overwritten on updates, so *it's **not** safe to edit them*. E.g. `wp-config.php` isn't a core file, because the vanilla installation comes only with the sample version of that file.